Match pattern then space then nothing
Below, you can see an example of strings. I'm interested to catching only strings similar to the first or second. Those strings has only one space after the last ']' then nothing.
With which regex can I resolve this task in the optimal way? I tried different ways, for example, ^.*?\s+.*?\s+.*?\s+.*?\s+.*?]\s$, but the number of steps to apply this regex exponentially grows depending on the string length.
2024-07-17T11:06:45.838 INFO (05b8-1bf8-1) [0002] [Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service] 
2024-07-17T11:06:45.839 INFO (0268-1574-1) [0810] [Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon] 
2024-07-17T11:06:45.880 INFO (150c-0e44-1) [5320] [Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy] %%4114 
024-07-17T11:06:43.549 INFO (0268-1574-1) [0801] [Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon] Process timings disabled
2024-07-17T11:06:58.592 INFO (0ec0-1d90-1) [9602] [Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Core]            svservice 2024-07-17T11:06:48:748 - 2024-07-17T11:06:48:754 (dur 0.01 seconds)


If you just want to match the full lines, ^.*\]\s$ would already be enough. https://regex101.com/r/5rkScz/1

The \s can be replaced with an actual space, if that is all you need to match. Otherwise, it will match any whitespace character, which might not necessarily be what you want.

The first four fields are non-whitespace chunks, so just use ^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\[(.*)\]\s$. In these situations, try to make the subpatterns as precise as possible.

Both variants is ok
Thanks for help, the answer was obvious =)

All variants above is OK for my particular situation:

^.*\]\s$
^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\[(.*)\]\s$
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3} INFO \(\w{4}-\w{4}-\d\) \[\d{4}\] \[.+\] $


You might try out this one.


const logs = [
    "2024-07-17T11:06:45.838 INFO (05b8-1bf8-1) [0002] [Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service] ",
    "2024-07-17T11:06:45.839 INFO (0268-1574-1) [0810] [Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon] ",
    "2024-07-17T11:06:45.880 INFO (150c-0e44-1) [5320] [Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy] %%4114 ",
    "2024-07-17T11:06:43.549 INFO (0268-1574-1) [0801] [Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon] Process timings disabled",
    "2024-07-17T11:06:58.592 INFO (0ec0-1d90-1) [9602] [Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Core] svservice 2024-07-17T11:06:48:748 - 2024-07-17T11:06:48:754 (dur 0.01 seconds)"
];

const pattern = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3} INFO \(\w{4}-\w{4}-\d\) \[\d{4}\] \[.+\] $/;

const filteredLogs = logs.filter(log => pattern.test(log));

console.log(filteredLogs);



